# Zed Graph with 3-X axis and 3-Y Axis

Tags: zedgraph

I m using zedGraph dll to save image of my graphs using points. Now I need to save a graphs with **1-X Axis and 3-Y axis**. Also with **3-X axis and 1-Yaxis**. Please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

For the Y axis, this issue is fairly simple. Just add a sufficient number of `YAxis` objects to the `GraphPane.YAxisList` and associate the curves with respective axis by setting the `YAxisIndex`.

After adding all curves to the graph, update the scales of the Y axes by calling `GraphPane.AxisChange()`.

Example:

```
var pane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

pane.YAxisList.Clear();
var y1 = pane.AddYAxis("First");
var y2 = pane.AddYAxis("Secnd");
var y3 = pane.AddYAxis("Third");

var curve1 = new LineItem(null, new[] { 0.1, 0.5, 0.9 }, 
    new[] { 0.8, 0.3, 0.1 }, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None) { YAxisIndex = y1 };
pane.CurveList.Add(curve1);

var curve2 = new LineItem(null, new[] { 0.1, 0.5, 0.9 }, 
    new[] { -0.8, -0.3, -0.1 }, Color.Green, SymbolType.None) { YAxisIndex = y2 };
pane.CurveList.Add(curve2);

var curve3 = new LineItem(null, new[] { 0.1, 0.5, 0.9 }, 
    new[] { -0.009, 0.001, 0.008 }, Color.Red, SymbolType.None) { YAxisIndex = y3 };
pane.CurveList.Add(curve3);

pane.AxisChange();
```

will produce the following result:

[image: Three Y axes]

For X axes, you would be able to have 2 different X axes by utilizing both the `XAxis` and `X2Axis` properties of the graph pane, and setting the `IsX2Axis` property to `true` for the curve that should reference the second X axis.

I do not know of a solution for more than 2 X axes, though.